# How to anchor a button in scrollview?

Tags: android, button, scrollview

i don't know what is it called, so I'll explain and maybe someone could help me to figure it out.

I have a scroll view with text.
Those are objective questions.
What I want to do is to put a small Button on the left bottom corner of the screen, so that I am able to scroll the text but the Button should remain fixed at that position.
It is like when the user is reading the questions and if he/she wants the answer he/she just clicks the Button and gets the answer.
I can put a Button in a LinearLayout, but I don't want the Button to be outside the scroll view.
It should be inside the ScrollView but has to remain fixed.

Please give me some direction.

Comment: you need a relative layout, button and scroll view

Comment: but that way the button will remail outside the scroll view. if i put a small button at bottom left corner of layout it should come on top of the text in my scrolview

Comment: You mean to say that u need a button inside the scrollview as well you want to fix it ???????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick. The idea is to not put the button in the scrolling area.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lot_of_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </ScrollView>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this should be the ouput
[image]

Comment: if i use this then the left part of the button will be blank

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: i want button inside scrollview and remain fixed. dont want button outside scrollview

Comment: yeah this is what i want. so if i scroll the button will stay there??

Comment: yes. but it does not fit your other requirement (have the button in the scroll view)

Comment: no i wasnt able to explain but this is how i wanted.

Comment: also is it possible to change the text on button according to the text displayed in scrollview.

Comment: programatically yes. update your question and accept answers.

Comment: accept answer?? do i have to click anything to accept?

Comment: i am not talking about your android app. if you are satisfied with my answer to your question you shouls accept it. if you have other questions, either create new ones or update this one.

Comment: that's what i am asking. how do you accept. do i click the upper arrow("this answer was useful")?

Answer (score -1):

You need to follow this format:

```
<RelativeLayout

    <ScrollView(Horizontal)


    </ScrollView>


    <Button
         use below ScrollView
         & margin From Left = 0dp
    />   

</RelativeLayout>
```